# Simple SQL Server query - If exists in one table need to return Y else N

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. One table `employeemaster` contains all of my employees in the company. Primary key = `EmpNo`.

The other table `employeeNoTime` contains a smaller list of employees that have no benefits. Primary key = `EmpNo`.

I want to query that will return 2 columns, the `EmployeeNo`, and Y or N.

`Y` if the employee number is in the `EmployeeNoTime` table.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Although `left join` *seems* like the right answer, it runs the risk that duplicates in the second table could result in duplicate results.

For that reason, I think `case` with a subquery is better:

```
select m.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from employeenotime n where m.EmployeeNo = n.EmployeeNo)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as notimeflag
from employeemaster m;
```

Answer (score 0):

A left join should do the trick:

```
SELECT    m.EmployeeNo, CASE WHEN n.EmployeeNo IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM      employeemaster m
LEFT JOIN employeeNoTime n ON m.EmployeeNo = n.EmployeeNo
```

Comment: I need it to return all the rows in Employee Master.   Won't this only return the rows that are in the EmployeeNoTime table?

Comment: @ArunJ no, that's why I use a **left** join.